# Two python module accessing each other

Tags: python, python-2.7

What happened is that I have this three module in my project. I would love to make them visible to each other.

Here is the directory structure

> ```
> MyProject
>     > web
>          > handlers.py
>     > models
>          > mymodel.py
>     > utils
>          > stringutils.py
> ```

Comment: Are you importing them in both files?

Comment: No, I'm trying to import mymodel and stringutils onto hanlers.py.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I should've included `__init__.py` inside the module, so it will visible to other modules of the project.

New directory structure is

```
MyProject
    > web
        > __init__.py
        > handlers.py
    > models
        > __init__.py
        mymodels.py
    > utils
        __init__.py
        > utils.py
    main.py
```

Now when I call handlers from the main.py, handlers can access models and utils.